# How to make field required only on create Easy Admin

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

There is no such option in `ImageField::new()` for example. It can be hidden on update for example but not required `false`. Don't see an event of easy admin [here](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/events.html) that can be helpful in such situation. My idea was to use such to turn of the required field before the update form renders.

```
ImageField::new(
            'image',
            $this->translator->trans('activity.image')
        )
            ->setUploadDir('/public/images/activities')
            ->setBasePath('/images/activities')
            ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[slug]-[timestamp].[extension]'),
```

This is my actual field. I don't know what more to add as code because there is literally nothing that I found. Tried with `AfterEntityBuiltEvent` but there I can take only the `entity` itself but not the form.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of `configureFields` is:

`public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable`

That means you can access the state of the form that is built through `$pageName` (yes, that's a name that looks strange). Configuring a required field by this state is possible like this:

```
yield ImageField::new('image', $this->translator->trans('activity.image'))
            ->setRequired($pageName === Crud::PAGE_NEW);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```php
ImageField::new('image', $this->translator->trans('activity.image'))
    ->setUploadDir('/public/images/activities')
    ->setBasePath('/images/activities')
    ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[slug]-[timestamp].[extension]')
    ->setFormTypeOptions(['required' => false])
;
```

With `setFormTypeOptions` you can overwrite any "standard" form type options.

See https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields.html#misc-options

Comment: Yes, but I need it on `create` only. Want it to be NOT required on `update`. This way I got it NOT required in both actions.

Comment: Well, then give a little more code, I can't guess how and where you use it